# kivy add a button to a specific location when pressing another button

Tags: python-2.7, kivy

I have a kivy/python setup with two screens and I would like to add a new button when the 'add button' button is pressed, and I would like to add the new button to a specific location. The Add button is on screen two and I would like the new buttons to appear in the GridLayout of the same screen. 
The python code I have is:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget



class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass

class AnotherScreen(Screen):
    pass

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass

class myApp(App):
    def build(self):
        pass
myApp().run()
```

And the kv file looks like this:

```
ScreenManagement:
    MainScreen:
    AnotherScreen:

<MainScreen>:
    name: 'main'
    GridLayout:
        id:grid_1
        cols:2
        rows:1
        Button:
            on_release: app.root.current = 'other'
            text: 'Another Screen'
<AnotherScreen>:
    name: 'other'
    BoxLayout:
        id:box_1
        GridLayout:
            id:grid_1
            rows:2
            cols:1
            Button:
                on_release: app.root.current = 'main'
                text: 'back to the home screen'
            Button:

                text: 'new buttons appear here..'
        Button:
            id:Add_buttons
            on_release: ????
            text: 'Add button'
```

thanks,
Marko

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a button which executes a special action, you should define it in main.py file:

```
class MyButton(Button):
    def on_release(self):  # or on_press
        new_button = Button(text='hello')
        self.root.ids.grid_1.add_widget(new_button)
```

Now, replace the button in kv code.

Comment: I had to use self.ids.grid_1.add_widget not self.root.ids... But it solved the problem very nicely

Answer (score 0):

Just tell the `GridLayout` to add a new widget:

```
#: import Button kivy.uix.button.Button
ScreenManagement:
    MainScreen:
    AnotherScreen:

<MainScreen>:
    name: 'main'
    GridLayout:
        id:grid_1
        cols:2
        rows:1
        Button:
            on_release: app.root.current = 'other'
            text: 'Another Screen'
<AnotherScreen>:
    name: 'other'
    BoxLayout:
        id:box_1
        GridLayout:
            id:grid_1
            cols:1
            Button:
                on_release: app.root.current = 'main'
                text: 'back to the home screen'
        Button:
            id:Add_buttons
            on_release: grid_1.add_widget(Button(text='new button'))
            text: 'Add button'
```

Note that I removed the `rows` attribute for `grid_1`, otherwise there won't be space for the new buttons.